# Answering a question twice?

Tags: discussion

May person have two answers showing for the same question?

If something happens (examples: a regulation change, a FAA interpretation) that invalidates an answer a person has provided, or if a person simply gains new information or has a change of thinking that would cause them to provide a substantially different answer than they already have, what is the most appropriate thing that person to do?  Simply provide a new answer?  It seems inappropriate to edit an old answer in a way that completely changes its meaning rather than simply expanding on it, especially given the upvote/ downvote system.

Is the person required to delete the old answer? For example if there has been a change in regulations and the old answer was a good answer to the existing situation at the time the question was asked, the answerer might want to leave the old answer stand as well just for the record.   Would it be inappropriate to simply edit it to put a sentence at the front saying something to the effect of "I no longer support this answer and here's why?"

Thank you.  PS no need to comment on overly long answers or continuous edits, I am getting the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can have multiple answers of the same question. Generally speaking, if you have a different point of view of a question you have already answered, it might be better to add a new answer instead of adding it in the older one.

However, if you notice that a regulation has changed, it is better to update the answer.

You can find more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60445/231188) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209/231188).